# Installing node.js on v1 Model B - segmentation fault

Tags: node.js, arm, failure

newbie here.
Raspberry Pi 1 Model B. Raspbian.
Had Adafruit WebIDE before.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ node -v
Segmentation fault
```

tried to uninstall:

```
apt-get remove nodejs
```

and reinstall, without any luck.

I assume it's something about armv6/7 binaries mismatch, right?

failed doing this: http://joshondesign.com/2013/10/23/noderpi

and this aswell: github.com/nodesource/distributions/issues/44

Currently I'm trying the instructions on this blog post:
http://stuff.stevenreid.uk/2015/03/22/install-node-js-and-grunt-on-raspbian/
but I'm not sure it's going the right way, and it's taking forever to compile.

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 5):

Eventually I've used a compiled version (node.js v12.02) by Conor O'Neill that applied a patch:
http://conoroneill.net/download-compiled-version-of-nodejs-0121-stable-for-raspberry-pi-here

The steps I've made:

```
wget http://conoroneill.net.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/node-v0.12.2-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz
tar -zxvf node-v0.12.2-linux-arm-pi.tar.gz
cd node-v0.12.2-linux-arm-pi
sudo cp -R * /usr/local/
cd
```

Then check all is ok by typing:

```
node -v
npm -v
```